# Problema com mapstruct com Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Eaí galera, tudo bem? Pessoal estou tentando implementar no meu projeto o mapstruct, porém, estou tendo um problema ao tentar utiliza-lo, onde basicamente quando eu faço o clean compile pra gerar a implementação do mapper, ele faz uma implementação passando todos os campos, enquanto eu gostaria de exercer a flexibilidade de apontar quais atributos serão mapeados. Essa é minha entidade de usuário:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    private String nome;

    @NotBlank
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    private String telefone;

    @NotBlank
    private String senha;
}
```

Esse é meu Dto de usuário:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UsuarioDtoEntrada {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    private String telefone;

    @NotBlank
    private String senha;

}
```

E esse é meu mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "usuarioDtoEntrada.name", target = "nome")
    Usuario getEntityFromDtoEntrada(UsuarioDtoEntrada usuarioDtoEntrada);
}
```

Meu pom está configurado da seguinte forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>asc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>asc</name>
    <description>asc</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.12</lombok.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=Spring</compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tentei aqui, porém, mesmo dessa forma a implementação ainda pega todo o objeto:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2022-02-20T15:57:51-0300",
    comments = "version: 1.4.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 15.0.2 (Amazon.com Inc.)"
)
@Component
public class UserMapperImpl implements UserMapper {

    @Override
    public Usuario getEntityFromDtoEntrada(UsuarioDtoEntrada usuarioDtoEntrada) {
        if ( usuarioDtoEntrada == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

        usuario.setNome( usuarioDtoEntrada.getName() );
        usuario.setEmail( usuarioDtoEntrada.getEmail() );
        usuario.setTelefone( usuarioDtoEntrada.getTelefone() );
        usuario.setSenha( usuarioDtoEntrada.getSenha() );

        return usuario;
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Alexsander! Este é uma campo para resposta. Você pode fazer comentários sobre a solução da outra resposta no campo comentários.

Answer (score -2):

Dando uma lida sobre o `lombok` + `mapstruct` o pre-processador do `lombok` precisa ser declarado antes do pre-processador do `mapstruct` para que a geração de código do `lombok` seja aplicada na geração de código do `mapstruct`, vê se isso resolve. [post do medium](https://sunhong22187.medium.com/using-lombok-mapstruct-to-write-mapping-services-instantly-4ca8820cab35)

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
   <source>1.8</source>
   <target>1.8</target>
   <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <path>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      </path>
      <path>
         <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
         <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
         <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
      </path>
   </annotationProcessorPaths>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Tinha entendido errado o seu problema. Se for para ignorar propriedade basta adicionar `ignore=true` para os atributos que você não quer mapear:

```@Mapping(source = "usuarioDtoEntrada.name", ignore= true)```

Mas não é uma boa prática criar um objeto inteiro pra preencher um atributo provavelmente seria uma boa tu revisar teu código